# mobile css are not working when i rotate the screen to landscape

Tags: css

here i done code for **style.css** for mobile device it the code works for mobile  portrait  size and when i rotate to landscape it call **default css** how to solve this issue

```
  @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    }
```

another terms are
 `@media (min-width: 481px) {}`
this for all sizes like tablet,pc ..

for this i checked in web developer tool in google crome

Comment: What's the resolution of the phone screen you are testing with? If it's over 480px when in landscape, your media query won't load. A safer media query method would be to target anything under 480px, e.g. `@media (max-width:480px) { mobile stuff }`

Comment: actually am testing using google crome web-developer tool .. changed as per you said then it got Mobile portrait (320x480) working fine but when it is Mobile landscape (480x320) it's not working..thanks for response @Timmah

Comment: No problem, that's the main downside of testing in browsers: you can't change the orientation. In your case, when you widened the browser window, it didn't make the orientation change, it simply got wider than 480px, so the media query no longer applied.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you rotate the device, it is screen is bigger than 480 px

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    ...Some Css Code
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
     ...Some Css Code
}
```

This will help you

or

you can find the landscape resolution than you can target media query with that.

For **Iphone 5** your media query must be like that

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```